# Is a set of continuous and bounded functions defined on [0,1] compact? Is it bounded?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose that $S=\{f\in C[0,1]|\|f\|<=M\}$ with $\|f\|=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. Is set $S$ a compact set? Is set $S$ a bounded set?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not compact, for $n>0$ consider $f_n$ defined by $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\in [1/n,1]$, $f_n(x)=1-nx, x\in [0,1/n]$. $\|f_n\|=1$, but you cannot extract a convergent sequence from it since $f_n$ converges towards $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0, x\in (0,1]$ and $f$ is not continue.